# OAuth Callback in the Glass Quick Starter Java App

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-glass

Got my Glass last week. Working on running the Java version of the Quick Starter Glassware demo. I am having trouble with the OAuth callback. Do I need set this up myself? Or is there source included in the sample somewhere? Please help!

**Clarification**: I have set up my own project with the Java Quick Starter app's code, deployed it in EC2 and have set up the Client-ID and Client-secret in the Google APIs Console. I set the Redirect URI as `http://<my server>/<my-app>/oauth2callback`. When I visit the app in the browser, I get a 404 error that /oauth2callback is not found. I also tried setting the Redirect URI to just my app's root, i.e. `http://<my server>/<my app>`. Strangely, I still get the same error that /oauth2callback is not found.

**Additional questions**: Can you please clarify what the callback URL needs to be set to? Is the handler code already included in the quick-start-demo app or do I need to provide that code?

Comment: Can you provide further details about what "trouble" you're experiencing and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have set up my own project with the Java Quick Starter app's code, deployed it in EC2 and have set up the Client-ID and Client-secret in the Google APIs Console. I set the Redirect URI as "http://<my server>/<my-app>/oauth2callback. When I visit the app in the browser, I get a 404 error that /oauth2callback is not found. I also tried setting the Redirect URI to just my app's root, i.e. http://<my server>/<my app>. Strangely, I still get the same error that /oauth2callback is not found.

Comment: Couple of follow-ups:   
Can you please clarify what the callback URL needs to be set to? Is the handler code already included in the quick-start-demo app or do I need to provide that code? Thanks!

Comment: Best practice is to update your question with more information, so people don't have to read through all the comments to understand the problem. Similarly, answers shouldn't be in comments either.

Comment: Answer updated with a link to another, similar, question that appears to have found a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482202/java-google-glass-starter-project-mapping-in-aws-ec2

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not using a URL that actually maps to your server and servlet container. Try hitting the URLs directly from a browser and make sure they show up in your server and servlet container logs.

The callback url needs to be set to the oauth2callback servlet, relative to the path that leads to the server and servlet container. I don't know how you've set these up, so I can only guess, but it sounds like the `<my app>` portion isn't correct.

The handler code is included as part of the webapp. See the [web.xml](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) file to see the path mapping and the servlet object that it maps to. In this case, around line 53, `oauth2callback` is mapped to the [com.google.glassware.AuthServlet](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/glassware/AuthServlet.java) class.

**Update**: See also the answer posted at [Java Google glass starter project mapping in AWS EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482202/java-google-glass-starter-project-mapping-in-aws-ec2)